# ERROR: Connect to Postgres on Localhost in Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose

I try to use docker-compose to build an application using Node.js and PostgreSQL(on localhost), but it still shows this error.

```bash
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:15432 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
   errno: -111,
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 15432
 }
```

There are my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile below, how should I fix?

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
  
  node:
    container_name: node-ts
    depends_on:
      - database
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

I try to add these syntax in `docker-compose.yml` to solve this error but none of them succeeded.

```yaml
links:
  - "database:postgres"
```

```yaml
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:172.0.0.1"
```

```yaml
environment:
  DATABASE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

The exported port only shows, how can you access the postgresql externally (from your machine). From intern, also for other containers, you can access the postgresql on database:5432.

So the correct DATABASE_URL is `jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/postgres`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this way is still not working:(

Comment: Yun what erros do you get now? peterh's answer is correct. You may be having connection poblems with the username/password, etc.